# Creating more than one user while provisioning azure linux vm via CLI

Tags: azure, ssh-keys, azure-cli, multiple-users, azure-vm-templates

I'm trying to create a linux virtual machine on azure via terraform and my requirement is to setup multiple user accounts on OS. I'm relatively new to Azure Cloud and went through some basic documentation but couldn't find what i was looking for.

I want to automate the process either via terraform or shell scripting by taking advantage of `azure-cli`. If anybody has anything relevant to my use case or point me towards direction for any alternative way to achieve this task then that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create more than one user in the provisioning time of the VM in Azure, you can use the cloud-init file to achieve that. Add the user in the cloud-init file like this:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: user1
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3<snip>
  - name: user2
```

For more details about the settings of the user, see [Users and Groups in Cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#users-and-groups).

The create the VM through the Azure CLI:

```
az vm create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name centos74 \
  --image OpenLogic:CentOS:7-CI:latest \
  --custom-data cloud_init_add_user.txt \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```

And the result of the test on my side here:

[image]

More details about the steps, see [Use cloud-init to add a user to a Linux VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/cloudinit-add-user). I suggest you can do this in the Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would this method also help me create user once i have provisioned the instance like update instance of create. I tried but that but didn't work, by any chance you're aware of any alternative way?
Many Thanks!

Comment: @opensourceJunkie Unfortunately, it just makes sense in the boot time. But you can add the user to the existing VM through CLI command [`az vm user update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-user-update).

Comment: @opensourceJunkie Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.