# How to create two admin users using azure templates?

Tags: azure, templates, authentication

I am preparing a new azure template to create few CentOs VMs on which there should be two admin accounts. I am able to create one admin user without problems but problem is with creating additional one.

I have tried to create two OSProfiles:

```
 "osProfile": {
     "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex(1))]",
     "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
     "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
  },
 "osProfile": {
     "adminUsername": "[parameters('secondUsername')]",
     "adminPassword": "[parameters('secondAdminPassword')]"
 },
```

I expect to have two users created during template deployment. But not able to find any information in azure documentation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that vms which I am creating are Linux machines CentOs

Comment: Possible you can use the cloud-init in the template to create more than one users, you can take a look at my another [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318189/creating-more-than-one-user-while-provisioning-azure-linux-vm-via-cli/55333983#55333983).

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use vm script extension to create additional users. vm creation api only allows to define one user. an example of using script extension can be found in the [template examples repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows/azuredeploy.json).

```
{
    "type": "extensions",
    "name": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('vmName')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "fileUris": [
                "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('ScriptFolder'), '/', variables('ScriptFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
            ],
            "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ', variables('scriptFolder'), '/', variables('scriptFileName'), ' ', variables('scriptParameters'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

or you can provide script command as is, something like:

```
New-LocalUser name -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 'pwd_goes_here'); 
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member name
```

you cant have linebreaks, so use `;` instead

Comment: I forgot to mention that vms which I am creating are Linux machines CentOs. Is there a way to do it on Linux machines?

Comment: doesnt matter, use linux script extension, you can find examples in the same repo, you can run custom scripts, you can also use cloud-init ([blog post](https://www.wintellect.com/arm-templates-and-cloud-init/))